# Why does margin-left:3rem; work, but margin-left:auto; doesn't?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a submit button:

```
<input class="my-class" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

when I put in my css:

```
.my-class{
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

it stays on the left side, I don't know why, because everything else works like:

```
    margin-left:1rem;
    margin-left:300px;
    margin-left:30%;
```

I'm completely confused!

Comment: auto will resolve to 0 for inline level element

Comment: Add `display:block;` to the input class and `margin-left` will work. https://jsfiddle.net/r45h98ta/

Comment: Thank you so much @MattHamer5

Comment: As your input element is an inline element, it will take margin auto as zero because inline elements reserves space after them to accommodate other inline elements, but if you make it a block element then it will honor the margin auto property, because the block elements reserve the horizontal space (thus making it 'available') for them only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `margin-left:auto` to be considered, you could add a `display:block` to your button like so

```
.my-class{
  display:block
  margin-left:auto;
}
```